# Inserting data into different referenced tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm sorry if my question is poorly formulated, I will explain in more detail below.

I write my API in hapi.js, so programming language is javascript.
Postgres version: 9.4.7

My database has 3 tables:

1. ratings
2. ratings_tags
3. tags

The table "ratings_tags" contains which ratings were tagged with what tags.

I have an api with an endpoint `/data/{id}`, where I can already get a single rating. The query that works, but might not be the best, is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    r.id, 
    r.score, 
    r.comment, 
    r.datetime, 
    r.type, 
    r.customer_id, 
    array_remove(array_agg(t.tag), NULL) as tags 
FROM 
    ratings r 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ratings_tags rt 
ON 
    r.id = rt.rating_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tags t 
ON 
    rt.tag_id=t.id 
WHERE
    r.id = $1
GROUP BY 
    r.id
```

I've written the frontend so I can edit a datapoint and now I want to save it again. I mainly care about the tags for now, but it should save the whole thing.
What I think it should do:

1. Insert all the rating information back into the table `ratings`
2. Insert all the tags that currently don't exist into the table `tags`
3. Insert the relations between the rating and the tags into the table `ratings_tags` UNLESS they already exist.
4. Somehow delete the relations that shouldn't exist anymore.

I'm thinking that it might be good to delete all relations between the rating being saved and its tags before saving the new one?

I tried a lot, but I just can't think of the correct query that the api should execute if I want to save a datapoint to `/data/{id}`, because of the ratings to tags relation.

---

UPDATE

Here are the first two steps that seem to work:

```
# STEP 1 (values are placeholders)
INSERT INTO ratings(rating_id, score, comment, datetime, type, customer_id)
    VALUES(r.id, r.score, r.comment, r.datetime, r.type, r.customer_id);

# STEP 2
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertTagsFromArray(varchar[]) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    new_tag varchar;
BEGIN
    FOREACH new_tag IN ARRAY $1
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO tags(tag)
            SELECT (new_tag)
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT tag FROM tags WHERE tag = new_tag);
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question as it stands is a bit too broad but I will have a crack

**1.** Insert all the rating information back into the table ratings

Well that's just a simple insert statement invoked by your programming language. You would need to retrieve the insert id generated. Your (unmentioned) programming language should take care of this for you.

**2.** Insert all the tags that currently don't exist into the table tags

As above. Congrats on being able to write a stored function for this task. You are not as much of a newby as you seemed to think.

At the same time, it's perhaps overkill to use one for this task. A simple insert with the looping being done in the programming language would probably be easier to work with.

This begs the question, have you chosen the correct programming language? Doesn't sound like it!

**3.** Insert the relations between the rating and the tags into the table ratings_tags UNLESS they already exist.

More efficient is to do what's is known as an UPSERT. Insert into the record and if it already exists to update it. In your case if you are not concerned about updating it you can simply ignore. This is more efficient than querying the database to find out what's in it and then inserting what's missing.

Again your programming language will be able to help you here.

**4.** Somehow delete the relations that shouldn't exist anymore.

No need for that. You need to add ON DELETE CASCADE to the relations and the database will take care of this for you automatically.

**5.** I'm thinking that it might be good to delete all relations between the rating being saved and its tags before saving the new one?

No that would be most inefficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! It's definitely simpler in more steps, thanks for that tip. I think I got the first two steps now, as they are simple inserts and I thought I had to do it in one query, but I still can't think of how to do the third step. Programming language is javascript as I'm programming the API with hapi.js. Postgres version is 9.4.7. I will update my post in a sec, maybe you can have a look if I did it correctly?

Comment: Sorry, first time I've even heard of hapi.js!

Comment: No problem. I'm only trying to write the correct queries at the moment, I will integrate them into the api later. I'm only interested in the queries for now.

Comment: Updated answer (section 2)

Comment: Uhm… Of course I can do the looping inside hapi.js. I guess I got so tangled up with all these queries that I just didn't think of it. Oh man^^ 
But anyways: Is it bad to write functions like that in postgres? Whats the best practice for database to api relation in this case?

Comment: Writing stored functions is hard so I try to avoid them as much as possible

Comment: Yes and no. Your comment helped me a lot and got me onto the right track, but it was no solution. I'm handling everything in the api now and only have to execute more simple functions. I did manage to right the complete query though. Easy upserts are not possible in the postgres version I use, so it was a little bit more complicated.